# SQLite 1.0.101.0 and entityframework 6.1.3, using LINQ, will not run

Tags: sqlite

I have developed a windows service that worked well but wanted to add access to SQLite databases. I developed a data manager project within the windows service to add the SQLite data handling. This was developed using VS2015.

The entity framework side of things worked well and built a model of the SQLite database and the service would start and run properly. The connection to the database also worked but when an attempt was made to run a query, I got the following error:

"Schema specified is not valid. Errors: 
Video.ssdl(2,2) : error 0152: No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SQLite.EF6'. Make sure the provider is registered in the 'entityFramework' section of the application config file. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more information."

The problem is that when I add the configuration and entity framework sections to the config file, the service won't start, giving the following error:

"The Media Sync Service service failed to start due to the following error: 
The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion."

Here are the configuration and entity framework sections:

```
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6, Version=1.0.101.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139" />
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
```

Has anyone else had this problem? I would be very grateful for any advice as to how to fix this.